# Is there a magic item I can use mythic points on to then cast the mythic version of that spell?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, spells, magic-items, mythic-adventures

Is there a way, say casting a spell from a scroll or whatever, that I can then spend a mythic point and cast the mythic version (assuming I know the mythic version).

It sounds like a staff might work?

If I know mythic cure light wounds, and I have a staff that can cast cure light wounds... can I use a mythic point when I cast CLW from the staff in order to cast the mythic version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Outside of the Ring Fering found, no spellcasting magic item will allow you to "upcast" the spells as Mythic.

Specifically, magic items that cast spells (wands, rods, scrolls, staves) do not benefit from any ability that "affects *your* spellcasting". See this [FAQ](https://paizo.com/paizo/faq/v5748nruor1fm#v5748eaic9n9y):

> **Does using a potion, scroll, staff, or wand count as "casting a spell" for purposes of feats and special abilities like Augment Summoning, Spell Focus, an evoker's ability to do extra damage with evocation spells, bloodline abilities, and so on?**
>
> No. Unless they specifically state otherwise, feats and abilities that modify spells you cast only affect actual spellcasting, not using magic items that emulate spellcasting or work like spellcasting.

"But wait! ShadowKras [pointed out](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/149801/28326) that Staves are different."

Staves have two specific exceptions (as per the FAQ's "Unless they specifically state otherwise"), neither of which Mythic :

> use the wielder’s ability score and relevant feats to set the DC for saves against their spells... can use his caster level when activating the power...

Also, from [Mythic Magic](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/alternative-rule-systems/mythic//mythic-magic/):

> Mythic spells can’t be crafted into magic items unless the item is an artifact (for example, you can’t brew a potion of mythic cure light wounds).

Additionally, [this](https://paizo.com/paizo/faq/v5748nruor1fm#v5748eaic9o94) isn't directly related but further supports this conclusion:

> **When casting a spell from a scroll, wand, or staff, can I apply one or more of my metamagic feats to that spell?**
>
> No.

Answer (score 2):

### Yes, the [Staff of Eldritch Sovereignty](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/artifacts/minor-artifacts/staff-of-eldritch-sovereignty-minor-artifact/)

Which is a *minor artifact*. One of the abilities of the staff is to allow a mythic character who knows the mythic version of one of the spells one the staff to cast the mythic version of that spell by spending one use of their mythic power:

> A wielder who knows the mythic version of one of the staff’s spells can cast such spells from the staff by expending one use of mythic power.

Which is similar to using your own mythic power to empower a spell cast, but using the staff instead of your own spell slots. However, that can only be used to cast mythic spells from those spells stored in the staff (*Arcane sight, Daylight, Knock, Mage armor, Mage hand, Touch of idiocy, Black tentacles, Cone of cold, Fireball, Greater dispel magic, Greater invisibility, Greater teleport, Lightning arc, Major image, Suggestion, Summon monster IX, Plane shift, Prismatic sphere and, Prismatic spray*).

Answer (score 1):

[Ring of Transcendent Spells](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/alternative-rule-systems/mythic//mythic-magic-items/other-magic-items/#TOC-Ring-of-Transcendent-Spells) is the closest to what you are looking for. You will have to scroll a fair ways down to find it. I even had to ask [my own question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/87966/23058) about it at one point.

Now, the ring means you do not have to KNOW the mythic version of the spell, but also means you cant augment it. So while a very versatile item, it still has a small flaw.

Now, normal rules are that when you cast a spell using a magic item, it does not benefit from your abilities such as CL, or ability scores. There are ways around this. But sadly cure light wounds is not mythic cure light wounds, so the item is different.